# Is there a way to simulate gyroscope movement on Android?

Tags: android, gyroscope

I want to simulate gyroscope shaking movement to get steps in health app. Is there a way to achieve this on my phone or on an emulator?

Comment: I think using Gyroscope would lead to an excess of data. Because it will give you information when you tilt the device as well. You can check the step counter sensor.
val sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
val sensor: Sensor? = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion

Comment: I mean is there an option to simulate the sensor movement so the app would think, that the phone shakes?

Comment: Of course yes. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#test-with-the-android-emulator check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Of course yes.
[1]: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/%E2%80%A6
check this out.

Also, keep in mind that the data you will receive from the emulator may have some accuracy issues. Recommended way would be to test it on the actual device for better accuracy.